# setLayoutParams on multiple layouts

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need to change the value topMargin of my layouts programmatically. I tried the following:

```
    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_ll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    spaceBtnWidth, buttonHeight);
    lp_ll.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp_ll.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp_ll.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    lp_ll.topMargin = rowDistance;

    ll3.setLayoutParams(lp_ll);
    ll4.setLayoutParams(lp_ll);
    ll5.setLayoutParams(lp_ll);
```

I want all my 3 layouts ll3, ll4 and ll5 to use the same properties from lp_ll. The problem is now that only my first layout ll3 takes it. The other two don't change. I even tried a different order and put the line where I set ll4 above the ll3 and ll5 lines. Anyways ll3 is being set and the other two don't change their properties. 
Thanks

Comment: What is the parent layout of your `ll[345]` layouts?

Answer (score 0):

for every layout create a copy of `lp_ll`

```
ll4.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lp_ll));
ll5.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lp_ll));
```

Comment: That crashes my application

Comment: this constructor added in API 19

Answer (score 0):

You can simply edit your code like this:

```
android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_ll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
spaceBtnWidth, buttonHeight);
lp_ll.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
lp_ll.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
lp_ll.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
lp_ll.topMargin = rowDistance;

ll3.setLayoutParams(lp_ll);
ll4.setLayoutParams(ll3.getLayoutParams());
ll5.setLayoutParams(ll3.getLayoutParams());
```

It will still do the same, i hope this helps.

Comment: Did not work. Again ll3 was good and the rest didn't do anything

Comment: Please post the complete code, so that we can better solve it. Thanks.